# nginx not serving JS, CSS files for PHP app behind ingress-nginx

Tags: php, docker, nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

Can't seem to get this working and need help on where I am going wrong.

Have an old PHP app subpathed at `/admin`. `ingress-nginx` forwards the traffic for it to an `nginx` server running in the Pod. I've verified  I can do the following and it serves the assets correctly:

- `kubectl port-forward <admin-pod> 4000:4000`
- `skaffold dev --port-forward`
- `docker run -p 4000:4000 <image>`

However, when I try to connect to access it through browser via the `minikube ip`, `192.168.64.5/admin` for example, I just get the following:

[image]

It displays the HTML, but none of the assets are loading because they aren't being found and I'm not sure why.

This is the `nginx` `default.conf` that serves the PHP application. I'd like to fix it in here, if possible, as opposed to in the `ingress.yaml` because they tends to mess with my other routes and took me a bit of time to get those working properly.

Here is what I have for those files:

```
# default.conf

server {
  listen 4000;
  # rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
  root   /usr/share/nginx/html/src;

  include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

  index app.php index.php index.html index.htm;

  client_max_body_size 500m;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
  }

  location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    # Mitigate https://httpoxy.org/ vulnerabilities
    fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi.conf;
  }
}
```

```
# ingress.yaml

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0"
    nginx.org/client-max-body-size: "500m"
  name: ingress-service-dev
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /adminv2/
            backend:
              serviceName: admin-new-cluster-ip-service-dev
              servicePort: 4001
          - path: /admin/
            backend:
              serviceName: admin-old-cluster-ip-service-dev
              servicePort: 4000  
          - path: /api/
            backend:
              serviceName: api-cluster-ip-service-dev
              servicePort: 5000
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: client-cluster-ip-service-dev
              servicePort: 3000
```

```
# Dockerfile

FROM php:7.3-fpm

# PHP_CPPFLAGS are used by the docker-php-ext-* scripts
ENV PHP_CPPFLAGS="$PHP_CPPFLAGS -std=c++11"

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y nginx \ 
    && apt-get install -y libpq-dev zlib1g-dev libzip-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install pgsql zip mbstring opcache 
RUN { \
        echo 'opcache.memory_consumption=128'; \
        echo 'opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8'; \
        echo 'opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000'; \
        echo 'opcache.revalidate_freq=2'; \
        echo 'opcache.fast_shutdown=1'; \
        echo 'opcache.enable_cli=1'; \
    } > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php-opocache-cfg.ini

COPY . /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer
COPY ./conf/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ./conf/entrypoint.sh /etc/entrypoint.sh

WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html/src

RUN composer install
# COPY --chown=www-data:www-data . /app/src

RUN mv "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-production" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"
RUN mv "/usr/share/nginx/html/conf/file_size.ini" "$PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/"

# EXPOSE 4000

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/etc/entrypoint.sh"]
```

```
# project structure

app-root/
  admin-new/
  admin-old/
    conf/
      company.conf
    src/
      css/
      js/
      Templates/
        index.tbs
      index.php
    Dockerfile.dev
  api/
  client/
  manifests/
```

```
# docker structure

/app
  conf/
    company.conf
  src/
    css/
    js/
    Templates/
      index.tbs
    index.php
  Dockerfile.dev
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The assets are probably loading from `/` rather than `/admin`. If you can't change the paths in the app, it might work better on it's own `host` rather than a `path`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to get all routes working by moving this path to a separate ingress config. Probably not ideal, but I just need it working until it is replaced in hopefully 6 months.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0"
    nginx.org/client-max-body-size: "500m"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      rewrite ^(/admin)$ $1/ permanent;
  name: ingress-service-dev-admin
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /admin/?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: admin-old-cluster-ip-service-dev
              servicePort: 4000  
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      rewrite ^(/new-admin)$ $1/ permanent;
  name: ingress-service-dev
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /new-admin/
            backend:
              serviceName: admin-new-cluster-ip-service-dev
              servicePort: 4001
          - path: /api/
            backend:
              serviceName: api-cluster-ip-service-dev
              servicePort: 5000
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: client-cluster-ip-service-dev
              servicePort: 3000
```

Comment: I had a very similar issue, I posted my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72340312/3667003